# Loop through every nth group of a groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently iterating over a groupby object in the usual way

```
for key, df_reduced in df.groupby(level='level_key'):
```

Is there an easy way to iterate through every nth group in the groupby instead? For example, the 1st group, 4th group, 7th group etc.

One way to do this would be

```
counter = 0
for key, df_reduced in df.groupby(level='level_key'):
    counter += 1
    counter = counter % 3
    if counter != 0:
        continue
```

Is there an cleaner way to do this, eg. for a standard python list to loop over every 3rd item I would do

```
for l in list[::3]:
```

Comment: How about iloc   df.iloc[::5, :] ...http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Comment: That raises `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'iloc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`

Comment: `df.groupby(level='level_key').size()[::3]` or `df.groupby(level='level_key').size().to_frame()[::3]` ?

Comment: Both of those give `TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try [GroupBy.nth](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html)

> GroupBy.nth(n, dropna=None)[source]
>   Take the nth row from each group if n is an int, or a subset of rows if n is a list of ints.
>
> Specifying as_index=False in groupby keeps the original index.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2],'B': [np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, columns=['A', 'B'])


print '\n', df.groupby('A', as_index=False).nth(1)
print '\n', df.groupby('A', as_index=False).nth(2)
print '\n', df.groupby('A', as_index=False).nth(0)
```

output

```
   A    B
1  1  2.0
4  2  5.0

   A    B
3  1  4.0

   A    B
0  1  NaN
2  2  3.0
```

Comment: Nice one! I didn't know about `nth`!

Comment: I don't want the nth item of each group, I want the 1st group, 3rd group, 5th group etc. I've update my question to make it clearer!

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question